# How should I provide guidelines for issues? (Github)

Tags: github, issue-tracking

I want to give the users of my repository some info on how they should report issues and what info they should provide. **What is the best way to present this information, and where?** I was hoping there would be a readme on the [/issues](https://github.com/wagenaartje/gynaptic/issues) tab but there seems no such option. Maybe I should create an 'issue' named 'Read before creating issue'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about the added clutter in the root directory of your project. 
 You can put `CONTRIBUTING.md`, `ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md`, and `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md` files in the project directory.

Yes, it will easy both parties to creating the issue or pull request fill all info.

[image: see in the pic]

> What is the best way to present this information, and where?

Put it into your this three files and file name should be same as here.
[More information about it](https://github.com/blog/2111-issue-and-pull-request-templates)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if github exclusively provides any such feature. Alternatively, you could include the guidelines (or link to- how to create an issue) in the readme.md file at the main branch of the project (e.g. a section #HowToCreateAnIssue along with other sections). At least, this is what I follow.

Answer (score 0):

For my Projects (and I guess thats how most People will handle it) I added a readme to the Projects repository and create a link to the most important wiki pages. The wiki will be managed as an additional repository and provides possibility to store Information and updates as needed.
If you also have a Webpage created this could also be a place to add some Information on how to participate as a contributor.